# How can I fix this issue with Yaml file?

Tags: docker, yaml

Hi I am trying to run docker-compose build --no-cache but I keep getting errors.

```
yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
  in ".\docker-compose.yml", line 1, column 1
expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>'
  in ".\docker-compose.yml", line 2, column 5
docker-compose.yml:
```

Please help me to to format this I looked online but I couldn't  find any linter that could do this I keep getting errors.
Thanks.
This is my docker composer file:
s is my docker file docker-compose.yml

```
   version: '3'
    services:
     #PHP-FPM service
        app:
            build:
                context: .
                dockerfile: Dockerfile
            container_name: store
            restart: unless-stopped
            tty: true
            working_dir: /var/www
             volumes:
                - ./:/var/www
                - ./docker-files/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
             networks:
                -app-network
    
            #Nginix service
            webserver:
                image: nginx-alpine
                container_name: store-webserver
                restart: unless-stopped
                tty: true
                ports:
                    - "8100:80"
                    - "8143:443"
                volumes:
                    - ./:/var/www
                    - ./docker-files/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
                networks:
                    -app-network
            #MariaDB service
            db:
                image: mariadb:10.5.6
                container_name: store-mariadb
                restart: unless-stopped
                tty: true
                ports:
                    - "3306:3306"
                environment:
                    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
                    MYSQL_DATABASE: store
                    MYSQL_USER: store
                    MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
                volumes:
                    - mariadbData:/var/lib/mysql
                    - ./docker-files/mariadb/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
                networks:
                    -app-network
            #Volumes
            volumes:
                mariadbData:
                    driver: local
            #Networks
            networks:
                app-network:
                    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Seems like your YAML file has some syntax errors, so not really related to nginx, PHP or Composer. Please only add tags thar are relevant to the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed some spacing issues on your YAML file, one of them is that the `version` and `services` sections are not on the same level, you have to know that docker-compose files and YAML have a strict syntax and a spacing might ruin everything for you here is a fix to your compose file, make sure to learn and read more about [docker-compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/).
Not sure what's the behavior of your environment but here is a correct YAML syntax for your example:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  #PHP-FPM service
    app:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: store
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        working_dir: /var/www
        volumes:
          - ./:/var/www
          - ./docker-files/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
        networks:
            - app-network

    #Nginix service
    webserver:
        image: nginx-alpine
        container_name: store-webserver
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        ports:
            - "8100:80"
            - "8143:443"
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
            - ./docker-files/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
        networks:
            - app-network
    #MariaDB service
    db:
        image: mariadb:10.5.6
        container_name: store-mariadb
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_DATABASE: store
            MYSQL_USER: store
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
        volumes:
            - mariadbData:/var/lib/mysql
            - ./docker-files/mariadb/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
        networks:
            - app-network
#Volumes
volumes:
    mariadbData:
        driver: local
#Networks
networks:
    app-network:
        driver: bridge
```

Comment: Thanks for this I will definitely  take a look at documentation

Comment: Glad It helped, stack is the place to help and get help so feel free to answer people's questions and learn more about StackOverflow.